# how to get uber api access token using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, uber-api

I am posting following data to [https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token]
my code:-

```
var postData = {
url:'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token',
headers:{"Authorization":"Token "+uberServerToken},
 qs:{
  client_secret:uberClientSecret,
  client_id:uberClientID,
  grant_type:'authorization_code',
  redirect_uri:redirectURIforAccessToken,
  code:req.query.code
 }
}; 
request.post(postData,function(err, response, body){
 if(err){
 console.log("Error @ POSTING:"+err);
 }else {
 console.log("body:"+body);
 res.end();
 }
});
```

but it is giving me response as {"error": "invalid_client"}

Comment: Make sure the uberClientID and uberClientSecret values are the same as the one's defined in the [Uber Developers Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard)

Answer (score 2):

Use this [node wrapper](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber) for the Uber API. It appears to be the most advanced one and I recently added support for `payment-methods` and `places`.

You can also check out my sample code from [Take Me Home Now!](https://github.com/agraebe/Take-Me-Home-Now/blob/master/app.js)

Answer (score 0):

use a package that supports oauth. It will be easier to deal with